# editing existing joomla website templates issue

Tags: joomla

I am trying to edit the name of the beez5 web template in Joomla 1.6 to myname by changing it in the templateDetails.xml file.

However, it does not show up with the changes.

What step am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make changes in `****_extensions` table also, for row where name is `beez_20`

Comment: do i need to make changes in the database or do i change the code file? Can you tell me what extension table you are referring to?